# The Sails.js controller action is called twice during every HTTP request

Tags: node.js, controller, sails.js

I wrote the following example controller using Sails.js:

#### `userController.js`

```
module.exports = {
    test: function(req, res){
        console.log('test')
        res.json('test')
    }
};
```

When I run sails.js and send it to that route (`user/test`), it appears to execute that code twice and outputs `test` twice in my WebStorm debug window:

```
"test"
"test"
```

How do I keep Sails.js from executing the same code twice?

Comment: I also stuck in same issue on sails 0.12

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your issue. I tried really hard to reproduce it.

I created the same controller you have in your question, and I ran the code -- but not in WebStorm, I ran it from the command line.  Since you're using `console.log("test")`, I should be able to see the console output `test` twice if your code is doing what you're saying it's doing, however, I couldn't get that to happen:

[image: Only output once]

As you can see from the screenshot, the console output `test` once, and the webbrowser output a response of `test`, which exactly matches the code you've given:

```
module.exports = {
    test: function(req, res){
        console.log('test') //output test to console
        res.json('test') //output test to the response
    }
};
```

I can't reproduce the issue as you've shown it; and there's no indication that controller is getting executed twice.

Comment: I found out -with help from other `sails` users- that this plugin was sending an extra second request, nothing to do with sails, that was the browser. The fact that you couldn't reproduce the issue was helpful. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-technology-notifier/fnpgnmindcbkjbpblcklealdhnogmlko